# Straight vs Three of a kind in flop

Tags: texas-hold-em

I was the one last to act in a hand with T:hearts:8:hearts:. UTG raised to ($3). Everyone else folds and I called.

Flop is J:hearts:9:diamonds:7:spades:. I flopped a straight and he bets the pot $8. I raised it to $16 and then he reraises to $32. I went all in with $100+ chips (as I was sure he has a three of a kind).

He called, and unfortunately 3:spades: and 3:hearts: showed up on turn and river and he had 99 with which he got full house.

What did I do wrong here? Whose hand was good post flop?

Comment: I am not sure if you made a miss play, you got your money in with the best hand and called his hand.  The risk of poker is that it is better to be lucky then good especially if you are only looking at one hand.

Comment: You got all your money in the pot when you were the favorite. You can't play it better than that.

Answer (score 1):

You got the money while you had the best hand and he sucked out on the turn and river. You played correctly.

Comment: i wouldnt say sucked out, although i know what you mean that V was behind. V has ~35% to win the pot, or 1 out of 3 times. Thats fairly frequent and shouldnt be too unexpected.

Comment: All I can say is that you're right.